# Inverse Laplace Transform of the following.

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the inverse laplace transform of $ F(s) = \frac{1}{2}\ln \left ( \frac{s^{^{2}}+b^{2}}{s^{^{2}}+a^{2}} \right ) $ with $ a,b \ \epsilon \ \mathbb{R} $ ?

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+transform+of+1%2F2ln%28%28s%5E2+%2B+b%5E2%29%2F%28s%5E2%2Ba%5E2%29%29) it's $\frac{\cos(at) - \cos(bt)}{t}$.

Comment: Yeah, but do you have any idea of how to get there?

Comment: I know the inverse laplace transform of $ \ln \left ( \frac{s^{2}+b^{2}}{s^{2}} \right ) $ is $\frac{2(1-cos(bt))}{t}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have written an answer that just requires a knowledge of laplace transform and differentiation under the integral sign

Answer (score 3):

$$F(s)=\mathcal{L}[f(t)](s)=\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$$
$$F'(s)=-\int_0^\infty tf(t)e^{-st}dt$$

---

You have:
$$F(s)=\frac12\ln\left(\frac{s^2+b^2}{s^2+a^2}\right)$$
$$F'(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+b^2}-\frac{s}{s^2+a^2}$$
now we know that:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{s}{s^2+b^2}-\frac{s}{s^2+a^2}\right)=\cos(bt)-\cos(at)$$
and from what I showed above we can say that:
$$-tf(t)=\cos(bt)-\cos(at)$$
$$f(t)=\frac{\cos(at)-\cos(bt)}{t}$$